# Get count of fields depending on existence in a linking table

Tags: mysql

If I have a table (e.g. doc) with ids 1-3 and a second linking table (e.g. docLink) that only has an entry if there is a linkId for example:

```
docId   linkId
1         1
1         2
1         3
3         1
```

I want to get the count of the number of docIds that do not have a linkId associated to them, so in this example the count would be 1 (id/docId = 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM doc d
LEFT JOIN docLink dl ON d.id = dl.docId
WHERE linkId IS NULL
```

As it is a `LEFT JOIN` all docs will be shown and if there is not a corresponding linkId in docLink, the linkId field will be `NULL`